# two div tag toggle functionality not working in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html

here it is javascript function and it is call when anchor tag click and when second       anchor tag not working in internet explorer i.e.Comments1 div not working properly 
        and div tag Disclaimer works in internet explorer please provide me some solution for this

```
<Script type="text/javascript"> 
     var $J = jQuery.noConflict();
  function ToggleComment() {
        if (!($J('#Comments1').is(":visible"))) {       
                  $J('#Disclaimer').toggle();
        }
}

function f_show_comments()  {       
        $J('#Disclaimer').hide();
        $J('#Comments1').show();
}

    </script>
    <html>
    <body>

        <div align="center" style="margin:10px 0;">
        <b><a href="" onclick="ToggleComment();return false;" style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; COLOR:#1F3E61; FONT-FAMILY: Georgia,Times New Roman, Times, serif;"> Click here to post your comments about this article.</a>
        <a href="" id="c" onclick="f_show_comments();return false;"  style="FONT-SIZE: 14px; color:#cc0000; FONT-FAMILY: Georgia,Times New Roman, Times, serif;" >Click here to accept the terms of this disclaimer.</a></b>
        </div>

        <div id="Disclaimer" style="display:none;">
            <P align=center><STRONG>SUMMARY DISCLAIMER AND TERMS OF USE</STRONG></P>

            <P>Minors should seek parental permission before submitting a post.</P>
            <P>All comments submitted may be reviewed and edited by the Communications department before going live on the website.</P>

            <P>For the complete Terms of Use, please <a target="_blank" href="http://www.newmiamiarch.org/Atimo_s/news/Terms of Service.pdf">click here</a>.</P>
        </div>

        <div id="Comments1" style="display:none;" align="center">
            <p align="left">Your comment will be submitted to the web stie.  
            While are contact references that will only be used by the staff  </p>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Which version of IE? Any errors? Does anything happen when links clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Chnage your JavaScript function body, and some html attribute value too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $J = jQuery.noConflict();

        function ToggleComment() {
            if (!($J('#Disclaimer').is(":visible"))) {
                $J('#Disclaimer').show();
                 $J('#Comments1').hide();
            }
        }

        function f_show_comments() {
            if (!($J('#Comments1').is(":visible"))) {
                $J('#Comments1').show();
                $J('#Disclaimer').hide();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div align="center" style="margin:10px 0;"> <b><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ToggleComment();" style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; COLOR:#1F3E61; FONT-FAMILY: Georgia,Times New Roman, Times, serif;"> Click here to post your comments about this article.</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="c" onclick="f_show_comments();"  style="FONT-SIZE: 14px; color:#cc0000; FONT-FAMILY: Georgia,Times New Roman, Times, serif;" >Click here to accept the terms of this disclaimer.</a></b>

    </div>
    <div id="Disclaimer" style="display:none;">
        <P align=center>
            <STRONG>SUMMARY DISCLAIMER AND TERMS OF USE</STRONG></P>

        <P>Minors should seek parental permission before submitting a post.</P>
        <P>All comments submitted may be reviewed and edited by the Communications department before going live on the website.</P>

        <P>For the complete Terms of Use, please <a target="_blank" href="http://www.newmiamiarch.org/Atimo_s/news/Terms of Service.pdf">click here</a>.</P>
    </div>

    <div id="Comments1" style="display:none;" align="center">
        <p align="left">Your comment will be submitted to the web stie.  
        While are contact references that will only be used by the staff  </p>

    </div>
```

Comment: if you need to use toggle function then hide only one div not both and use only ToggleComment function for both links